# Implementing a specific font in Email in an asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-mvc-4, stringbuilder, font-family

I want to set a specific font(helvetica neue) for the Email Content, which will be fired due to any user opertaion. It is not the base font i am using, and the email content is generated by StringBuilder.

Looking forward for suggestions

Thanks & Regards

Arka

Comment: Why not use inline styling and use the specific font you want ?

Comment: You need to share the relevant code what you have tried and the results and expected behavior.

Comment: ` EmailMessage.AppendLine("<p align='left' style='text-align: left; color: #635c58; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 21px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;'><br/>Take a gander here:</p>");`

Answer (score 0):

Send the email as HTML and use Google Web Fonts or similar hosted font service in the inline CSS styling.

Answer (score 0):

There is a suggestion.
Set MailMessage property IsBodyHTML is equal to True.

```
MailMessage mailMsg= new MailMessage();
-------
mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```